# A question about an epsilon-delta proof

Tags: functions, continuity

Currently, I am stuck on a question:
 Let $ g : [ 0 , \infty ) \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ be defined by $g(x)=  \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^2  & \mbox{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
  3x & \mbox{if } x > 1
 \end{array}
\right.$
Prove: For $\epsilon =1$, $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|g(x)-g(1)|>\epsilon$.

I know how to do a normal epsilon-delta proof with continuity. But now $\epsilon$ is fixed and I do not know how to handle this problem. My work so far:

Proof: Let $g$, $\epsilon$, and $x$ as above: 
$|g(x)-g(1)|=|x^2-1|=|(x+1)(x-1)|=|x+1||x-1|=(|x|+1)|x-1|$

I have no clue how to get rid of the $|x|$, normally I would use that $|x|<|a|+\delta$, but since we do not have an $a$ here, I am pretty sure we cannot use that.

Any hints would be appreciated, preferably no full answers as I have to do it myself one day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your $g$ is piecewise defined. Look at both pieces.

Comment: I think you have an inequality direction typo there, $|g(x)-g(1)|<\epsilon$ makes more sense to me.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I wish I was, but the question clearly states $|g(x)-g(1)> \epsilon$ Daniel Fischer, what do you mean?

Comment: You want to find an $x$ with $\lvert x-1\rvert < \delta$ but $\lvert g(x) - g(1)\rvert > 1$. Try for example $x_1 = 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}$ and $x_2 = 1+\frac{\delta}{2}$.

Comment: $x_1$ gives $g(x_1)=1-\delta + \frac{\delta ^2}{4}$ and $x_2$ gives $g(x_2)=3+1.5 \delta$. The difference is $g(x_2)-g(x_1)=2+2.5 \delta - \frac{\delta ^2}{4}$ So we have to find a $\delta$ s.t. $2+2.5 \delta - \frac{\delta ^2}{4}=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you'er busy showing that $g$ is *discontinuous* at $x = 1$.

For $0 \leq x < 1$, $| g(x) - g(1) | = 1 - x^2$ and for $x > 1$, $| g(x) - g(1) | = 3x - 1$. Given some $\delta > 0$, you have to either find an $x \in (1 - \delta, 1)$ such that $1 - x^2 > 1$ or an $x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$ such $3x - 1 > 1$.

Now the first one is not going to work, which was to be expected, because $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so we better try the other one. So let's try $x = 1 + \delta/3$, which satisfies $x \in (1, 1 + \delta)$ and also $3x - 1 = 2 + \delta > 1$.

Comment: So this would be correct? Proof: For $0 \leq x \leq 1, |g(x)-g(1)|=1-x^2$ and for $x>1, |g(x)-g(1)|=3x-1$. Given some $\delta > 0$, we have to find a $x \in (1-\delta, 1)$ such that $1-x^2>1$ or a $x \in (1, 1+\delta)$ such that $3x-1>1$. \\*
Since $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x^2>0 \Rightarrow 1-x^2 < 1$. Hence, this will not work. \\*
If we let $x=1+\frac{\delta}{3}$, $3x-1=2+\delta > 1$ \\*
Conclusion: For $\epsilon =1$, $\forall \delta >0$, $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|g(x)-g(1)|>\epsilon$, namely $x= 1 + \frac{\delta}{3}$.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be: for $x>1$, $|g(x)-g(1)|=3x-3$ @Magdiragdag ?

Comment: @NigelOvermars No, $g(1) = 1$, since it falls in the case $0 \leq x \leq 1$. This is basically the reason you have to look at the case $x > 1$ for your $x$.

Comment: @NigelOvermars And yes, that would be correct, although if you want to just give a short proof without any explanation, I'd just do the following. Proof: Take $\delta > 0$. Let $x$ be $1 + \delta/3$. Then $|x-1| = \delta/3 < \delta$ and $|g(x) - g(1)| = |3(1 + \delta/3) - 1|  = 2 + \delta > 1$.